# HTML Element Hierarchy

Tags: html, element, hierarchy

I want to change the color of title by using a separate CSS file. My styling code is like below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#Organization" data-toggle="tab">Organization</a></li>
```

and here is the styling code:

```
 .ul .nav .nav-tabs .li .a{
 color:red;
 }
```

Please help. I could not find the correct way

Comment: .ul.nav-tabs li a{ color:red; } Please try this.

Comment: @ManishJesani `li` and `a` is Tag not a Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to put the class dot on all the selectors - also you are not closing your `</ul>` - although that could jst be a typo in here.:

```css
ul.nav.nav-tabs li a{color:red;}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#Organization" data-toggle="tab">Organization</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
 ul.nav.nav-tabs > li > a
```

instead of

```
 .ul .nav .nav-tabs .li .a
```

Because ul, li and a are tags, so they don't require dot prefix

Comment: Thank you for your responses. But still could not get the correct result.

Comment: <div class="col-md-10">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><a href="#Organization" data-toggle="tab">Organization</a>  </li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#Reporting" data-toggle="tab">Reporting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#PerDetails" data-toggle="tab">PerDetails</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Travel" data-toggle="tab">Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Education" data-toggle="tab">Education</a></li>
....

Comment: check in inspect element of browser, may be styles are overridden

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.nav.nav-tabs li a {
 color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul a:first-child{color:red;}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#Organization" data-toggle="tab">Organization</a></li>
</ul>
```